# How to enable maven to download repository from central repository (Macbook M1 + IntelliJ)?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apple-m1

I installed JDK and Intellij. I am able to run plain projects but when i import maven project or make a new maven project, I get error. The probelm is maven is not able to download jars from central repository. I am using macbook pro (M1), I tried it on a windows system, it worked fine without any additional settings, I also tried on my friend's Macbook(intel) ,It worked normally but in my system i get error. .jars are not being downloaded in .m2 folder.

Please see the error below.

[Click here for error that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8oVZ.png)

All settings are default, which are working on other mac systems and windows system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Network worked for me.

Maven was not able to download jars as it was not able to connect to the repository. Previously when I tried to access the repository using the browser, I was able to do so and I concluded that the error was due to some wrong configuration.
Using terminal I tried to ping the repository and I wasn't able to do so. The actual problem is not known yet, because if there was error in my router configuration then i would not have been able to access it via intellij on windows system, i was ablr to do so. It seems the problem lies between my system settings and how it interacts with the router.
In my case using mobile network as hotspot worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong MavenCentral URL.

This is probably an error in the `settings.xml`.

Comment: The problem appeared to be same, i was using default entries in settings.xml. The problem is my router settings, maven is not able to access central repository, although it is accessible via browser. I used mobile data as hotspot and things worked.